# Sending signal to parent process with kill logs me out

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, kill

I'm learning signals and processes on Linux(Ubuntu) and writing simple programs in C.

Here's the code.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#define MAXFD 20
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h> // standard input/output
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> // string operations
#include <dirent.h> // dirent
#include <sys/stat.h> // filestat
#include <errno.h> // errno
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define ERR(source) (perror(source),\
                    fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
                    kill(0,SIGKILL),\
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE))

volatile sig_atomic_t last_signal = 0;
int sig_count=0;

void usage(char *name){
    fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: %s t \n",name);
    fprintf(stderr,"t - how often send SIGUSR1 signals\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void sethandler(void(*f)(int),int sigNo){
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act,0,sizeof(struct sigaction));
    act.sa_handler = f;
    if (-1==sigaction(sigNo,&act,NULL)) ERR ("sigaction");
}

void countSigHandler(int sig){
    sig_count++;
    printf("Parent received a total of %d SIGUSR2\n",sig_count);
}

void sigchld_handler(int sig) {
        pid_t pid;
        for(;;){
                pid=waitpid(0, NULL, WNOHANG);
                if(pid==0) return;
                if(pid<=0) {
                        if(errno==ECHILD) return;
                        ERR("waitpid");
                }
        }
}

void child_work(int t){
    struct timespec ts = {0,t};
    int i=0;
    sethandler(SIG_DFL,SIGUSR1);
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        //nanosleep(&ts,NULL);
        sleep(t);
        if (kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1)) ERR("kill");
        //if (kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1)) ERR("kill");
        printf("[%d] sending SIGUSR1 to %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
}

void parent_work(){
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int t;
        t = atoi(argv[1]);

        sethandler(sigchld_handler,SIGCHLD);
        sethandler(countSigHandler,SIGUSR1);    

        pid_t pid;
        if ((pid=fork())==-1)ERR("fork");

        if (pid==0) child_work(t);
        else {
            if (kill(0,SIGUSR1)) ERR("kill");
            //parent_work();
            //while(wait(NULL)>0);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run it from the terminal ( the compiled file ) with a t of 1, it logs me out and I have to type my password again to log in (also all programs are closed when I log back in).

If I comment the line in child_work that uses kill to send a signal, it runs ok.

What's going on here? Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you call kill with a pid of 0?

Comment: This one just sends the signal to all processes of a given group. And this one doesn't cause any crashes.

Comment: Are you sure? Because when you run a process in your shell, it's in the same process group as your shell and potentially your entire session. As `SIGUSR1` has a default disposition of “terminate the program,” this would kill all processes in the same process group which should case the symptom you see.

Comment: Well I commented it and it still happens. If I comment the one in the child_work, it doesn't happen.

Comment: That's a good argument. What happens if instead of SIGUSR1 you use a signal that is ignored by default? Could you try to reduce your program to a minimal self-contained example?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this system on my machine. Are you running this as root? How are you logged in (via X server, tty, etc) when you observe this?

Comment: your ERR() macro also send KILL to 0. Did you try removing this kill? The goal is to reduce the kills that are performed (and I don't want to kill my session by trying your code ;)).

Comment: What do you try to achieve by calling `kill` with a pid of 0? Why do you do this, especially without creating a new process group for your process? You do realize that every call to `kill` with an argument of 0 will usually also kill the process that invoked it and some more as all these are in the same process group?

Comment: FUZxxl is right: if your goal is to kill all processes that should be spawned (on emergency exit for example) you should create a new group.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. What happens when the parent finishes and then the child process sends signals to the parent?

Comment: Well, zombies should be attached to process 1 if I remember well. But you should not be able to kill init. Note: I managed to reproduce that (killing my session) even with removing the kill from ERR... Will have a look later.

Comment: Ok thanks :) I really dont have a clue why that happens

Comment: @nos False, that would happen with a pid of `-1`. A `0` pid only kills every process in the same process group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. I modified the code to remove all kills but added PID prints. Here is the sequence for t=0:

```
I am 12684
pgid=12684  // I printed the PGID to be sure
[12685] sending SIGUSR1 to 12684
[12685] sending SIGUSR1 to 11451
(…) // same line repeated, from the for loop
```

With t=1 it is directly 11451. You were right, because on my session process with PID 11451 is:

```
init --user
```

started as my user. So I'm allowed to send signals to it. And so yes, after father dies the child is attached to init, here "my" init, and so `getppid()` points to it and the code kills init!

If you re-activate the `wait()` loop the output is different as I only see the father PID (of course without real kill the father is still alive).

Not sure about why this "private" init is used (don't followed recent changes in Ubuntu). Knowing that, and to prevent such behavior, I would suggest to store the PID at process starting (before any forks) and to use this stored value after that in children. This way you are sure to "kill" the right target, or to kill nobody if the father dies for any reason.